# How to use OAuth with Google AdWords / AdSense API?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, adsense, google-ads-api

all
I successfully can use OAuth to work with GA service, there are a lot of code already written for this. And for security purposes, i can't store user google account credentials.
So, i prefer to use OAuth.

But, i can't found any examples how to use OAuth with Google Adwords / AdSense services.

Because they use SOAP and ClientLogin, but on this page http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html
Google suggest to use OAuth instead of ClientLogin (but at this page http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/ no AdWords / AdSense scopes defined)

Does anyone have a solution?

Thx

Comment: Not sure about adsense but the last time i checked, Adwords only allowed authentication using ClientLogin (since only the SOAP service is available)

Comment: The DoubleClick for Publishers API has a section describing how to use the 
OAuth playground, and the AdWords API is very similar. 
  http://code.google.com/apis/dfp/docs/developers_guide.html#oauth

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Google's OAuth libraries quite easily to accomplish this, but the AdWords API is a little more tightly controlled than other Google API services.

The AdWords SDK includes an `AdWordsUser` entity which handles OAuthing for you, you just need to configure it properly.

Step 1: Sign up for the AdWords API.  Upon approval, you will get a **developer token**.
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup

Step 2: Create an application at the Developers API console.

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com
- Click on Credentials
- Create a new "Client ID", which will generate **Client ID and Client Secret** credentials.  Make sure you pick the right application type (native/embedded vs web application).  You will need to whitelist the redirect URLs of your own application here to allow the end user to bounce back to the app.  If this is a server-side application, choose "Client ID for native application".  You will use fancy things like refresh-tokens to gain access.

Step 3: Grab an Adwords SDK in the language of your choosing (https://github.com/googleads) and configure it with the credentials needed.

**Note**
When requesting scopes in OAuth if you're not using the AdWords API Client SDK, make *sure* to include the scope `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"` otherwise the credentials you get back won't actually let you do anything against the AdWords API.  This is critical! (http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/07/new-oauth-20-scope-for-adwords-api.html)